# Documentation for Finer Points of FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm creating a general-purpose FTP class for .NET. I seem to have things working nicely but there are a few details I'm a little unsure about. And documentation such as that on MSDN provides absolutely no information on these details.

For example, when performing request methods such as `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile` and `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory`, can I safely ignore the contents of the response? Or could there ever be information in the response that I need to check for?

I'm pretty sure `GetResponse()` throws an exception for pretty much all error conditions, but how can I be sure? Again, the docs just don't seem to cover this type of information.

Can anyone address this question or recommend the documentation I should be using?

Comment: Experience taught me that .NET FTP classes don't work for every FTP server. So I highly recommend you to use those classes only for specific servers. When you don't know which server your app will connect to, you should use a third-party library.

Comment: @Jader: Well, thanks for that. Of course, those third-party libraries must work somehow. Perhaps you're saying I need to dig deeper if I want to be compatible with every server.

Comment: @Jon Well, I'd recommend reading the FTP protocol standard if you want a deeper understanding

Comment: @Earlz: Right, that's what I'm concluding. Unfortunately, that won't tell me more details about FtpWebRequest or when it may raise an exception and when there might need to be other tests to detect error conditions.

Comment: @Jon well, if all else fails, I believe Microsoft released all of .Net's source code(though under a non-opensource license) so you could dig through it and document it yourself.. or all else fails use reflector and trial and error :P

Comment: how about this free ftp client: http://dotnetftpclient.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can ignore these; however I would suggest ensuring that these are accessed in a controlled manner and within try...finally tags, ensuring the response is closed in the finally tag:

```
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {
                       return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure? Could you please provide proof link?